# Computer not shutting down

Tags: windows-7, drivers, freeze, shutdown, device-manager

I have Microsoft Windows 7 Professional installed on my laptop (HP Pavilion G4 Notebook PC).

Since a couple of weeks my laptop is not shutting down properly. When I click on the shut down button the logging off screen appears then the shutting down screen appears, but after that nothing happens.

I mean the shutting down screen is present all the time and the system does not shut down. The circle next to the shutting down keeps on rotating. I have left it for hours but still nothing happens. Eventually I have to shut it down by pressing the power button for some seconds. But the next time when I start the system, the windows starts normally.

I have tried to find solution for it. Mostly the solution that I found was to `check/uncheck the 'Allow computer to turn of this device to save power' in the power management tab of some driver in device manager` but nothing seems to work for me.

Could anyone please help me with my problem?